# Wordpress limiit query results

Tags: mysql, wordpress

How can I limit query result in wordpress let's say I want to display just 4 last posts from a category but starting from second row, I know that in MySql is like this:

```
select * 
from table_name 
limit 4, 1
```

In wordpress should be something like this:

```
('cat' => get_category_id($catname), 'posts_per_page' => 2, 1);
```

But it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, i just needed to use the offset variable instead of paged.

Check here for details

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/query_posts-offset-and-pagination

Answer (score 2):

Use the `paged` (and the `$paged` WordPress variable) argument. All info here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22paged.22_parameter_to_a_query

Comment: This is good but when i make the $paged = 2 it displays 4 other posts. What i want is to display 4 posts but starting from second row.              Lets say we have 5 posts and i just wand to show 4 last posts?

Comment: The use the offset parameter